# DataSet not storing Data

Tags: vb.net

The Visual Basic sample code below stores the retrieved data into the myVariable variable. However, it does not get stored into the ds "myTable" table.

The original data is coming from a SQL DB, which is stored into a Datatable. The Datatable shows the data in the form of a CheckedListBox (the checkedlistbox shows two forms of data: UCSNumber, UCSDesc

```
Dim ds As New DS_UsersStatus()
Dim myVariable = LstBranch.CheckedItems.Cast(Of DataRowView).Select(Function(o) ds.Tables("myTable").Rows.Add(o.Item("UcsNumber"), o.Item("ucsDesc")))
```

Comment: I'm sorry but your question makes very little sense to me at least.  Maybe you could edit it and a a more clear description (Please edit the question, not add a comment) of the problem and what exactly you are trying to achieve

Comment: @Hursey I think what im trying to achieve is pretty clear; im trying to get the data stored into the dataset called "myTable"